# Connecting shared network drive through scheduled task

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks, network-drive

Actually, i have one scheduled task in my application to trigger multiple batch files based on timings ( maintaining like crontab).  I dont want store the password of the my account, i have selected "**Do not store password**" option when i created schedule task.

Now, i tried to connect the network drive through one pf the batch file which is triggered by this schedule task, i am getting **access is denied** error.

When i run the batch file normally (not triggered by schedule task), it is working without any issues.

Could you please help me to connect the network drives through the schedule task.

Thanks,

Comment: Run in a command prompt window `net use /?` and read. You must specify the __password__ and the __user name__ with __domain__. If you are logged in, Windows uses automatically the login password of the current user and the domain\username of the current user. But as you have specified to not store password encrypted by Windows for the task, you have to specify the password readable for everyone with read access to the batch file in the batch file itself on line with `net use`. This is not a good idea, isn't it.

Comment: @Mofi, thanks for your reply. Yes. i dont want to put the password in the batch file itself.

Comment: Thanks All, I am able to connect the network shared drive using net use command